# Can't find io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder when starting project in a docker container

Tags: java, docker, maven, quarkus, jjwt

When starting my Quarkus project locally with `mvn quarkus:dev` I have no errors when executing a function which utilizes JJWT.
However when I export my project into a docker container it gives me an error stating that it can't find DefaultJwtBuilder.

When dockerizing my project I first execute

`./mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true`

as stated in [the Quarkus docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image#container-runtime) for creating a Linux executable without GraalVM.

Followed by

`docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native -t quarkus-quickstart/getting-started .`

When starting the project with Docker Desktop I get the error.

The dependencies I have in my pom.xml are the following.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
  <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.11.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
  <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
  <version>0.11.2</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
  <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>0.11.2</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The detailed error message is

```
io.jsonwebtoken.lang.UnknownClassException: Unable to load class named [io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder] from the thread context, current, or system/application ClassLoaders. All heuristics have been exhausted. Class could not be found. Have you remembered to include the jjwt-impl.jar in your runtime classpath?

at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Classes.forName(Classes.java:92)
at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:136)
at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder(Jwts.java:141)
at org.roguedevelopment.logic.JWT.GenerateJWT(JWT.java:21)
at org.roguedevelopment.logic.JWT_ClientProxy.GenerateJWT(JWT_ClientProxy.zig:224)
at org.roguedevelopment.logic.AuthHandler.LoginUser(AuthHandler.java:62)
at org.roguedevelopment.logic.AuthHandler_ClientProxy.LoginUser(AuthHandler_ClientProxy.zig:164)
at org.roguedevelopment.controllers.AuthController.login(AuthController.java:72)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:643)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:507)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:457)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:459)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:419)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:393)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:68)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:131)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:37)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:94)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
```

The dockerfile I use to build my docker image is

```
## Stage 1 : build with maven builder image with native capabilities
FROM quay.io/quarkus/centos-quarkus-maven:20.2.0-java11 AS build
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app/
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml -B de.qaware.maven:go-offline-maven-plugin:1.2.5:resolve-dependencies
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
USER root
RUN chown -R quarkus /usr/src/app
USER quarkus
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml -Pnative clean package

## Stage 2 : create the docker final image
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
WORKDIR /work/
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/*-runner /work/application

# set up permissions for user `1001`
RUN chmod 775 /work /work/application \
  && chown -R 1001 /work \
  && chmod -R "g+rwX" /work \
  && chown -R 1001:root /work

EXPOSE 8000
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because your are using native mode and the `io.jsonwebtoken` library seems that does not support it.

Quarkus does its best to integrate libraries and make them work with native mode, by adding the pieces required by native mode. For native mode limitations, please check this link: https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/Limitations/.

Please check Quarkus JWT support that works with native mode: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt.

If you really want to keep using `io.jsonwebtoken` you may need to provide additional metadata to the native image build: https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips.

Answer (score 8):

This does not work becuase jjwt-impl .jar needs to be imported

Use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know, I'm quite late. I got the same issue with jjwt 0.11.5. I didnot had `<artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>`.

I added this dependency and got some Serializer error

```
Unable to find an implementation for interface io.jsonwebtoken.io.Serializer using java.util.ServiceLoader. Ensure you include a backing implementation .jar in the classpath, for example jjwt-impl.jar, or your own .jar for custom implementations.
```

Then i added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId> <!-- or jjwt-gson if Gson is preferred -->
    <version>0.11.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

and changed all the versions to 0.11.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked in my case, so I have created a new spring boot project and copied the below dependency to my POM.XML then copied all my code to a new project, and then ran it.

After that, it worked fine. I spent 6 hours and couldn't able to figure out the problem of why my old project threw errors as both old and new are same

Note I am using Java 11

```
         <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).